# How to deal with library of images in android?

Tags: android, apk

I'm rewriting existing Windows application to android.

My application is a kind of customizeable picture communicator for people with disabilities. It uses about 300 categorized images and this number is growing. They take 100-300kB each.

In Windows version I just have a folder with subfolders and I'm copying it to `Program files\My application` in installer. During runtime I just read images and folder tree from filesystem.

Now I want to re-use this folder structure with images in Android application, but my knowledge about Android development is poor.

---

My question:

**How can I "include" whole folder of images in apk file and make it "expand" to somewhere in filesystem during installation?**

---

My minSdkVersion is 21.

Comment: Your questions will ultimately lead to more universal questions about how Android applications work.  Think how you would do I/O operations via Java code on any system, why would Android be so different? Same could be said for doing http get requests - the same as any other Java application.

Comment: @MarkKeen Handling I/O is not a problem for me. Building apk file that will create same folder on device is a problem.

Comment: In Android resources are handled more easily. I suggest you read more about [Android resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html).

Comment: If you are loading all the images "programmatically only", then you can dump all your directory tree into the **assets** folder. The **assets** folder maintains the hierarchy.

Comment: @SumitAnantwar This is what I need. Thanks. You can post that as answer.

Comment: @Kamil, I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are loading all the images "programmatically only", then you can dump all your directory tree into the assets folder. The assets folder maintains the hierarchy.
You will be using AssetManager for accessing the files. Note that files read from assets are simply **stream of bytes**.

As per the **AssetManager** [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)

> Provides access to an application's raw asset files. This class presents a lower-level API that allows you to open and read raw files that have been bundled with the application as a simple stream of bytes.

Check this [tutorial](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/) for a head-start.

Comment: `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open(filename));` does the job. I can't believe that this is so simple.

Answer (score 1):

My question(s):

> How can I add a folder with 300 images to my Android app?

You would get `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` which is where directories like `Pictures` are, or for app internal storage `context.getFilesDir()` - which is private to your app - this is the location where databases and preferences are.

> download from internet during first application run and store them in filesystem?
>       copy my folder to resources in Android project?

You could hook into the `onCreate()` of either your `Application` class, or launcher `Activity` hooks.

**Few things to note:**

If you want to store directly in internal app folder you only require Internet permissions in your Manifest, however if using external sotrage you will need READ/WRITE permissions, and targeting Marshmallow+ will require handling runtime permissions.  Also downloading 300 images without user consent could be bad practice, consider letting user decide first.

As you have mentioned you are happy with handling I/O I won't go into any detail regarding this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP is asking about bundling the images with the package

Comment: @SumitAnantwar Not the original question before editing, which my answer is based upon - hence highlighting OP's questions in my answer.

Comment: sorry, I had not read the question before editing.

Comment: @SumitAnantwar no problem - the goal posts changed on me mid answer ;)

Comment: Thanks you both guys. @MarkKeen helped me to write better question by missunderstanding my (not well written) question.